# Rotate UIButton and preserve its size

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to rotate buttons, that are shaped as a square (65 x 65). After I rotate them, the buttons change their sizes. Is there any way, to make a rotation and keep the size?

**Code:**

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

self.stealthButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
self.recButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
self.toggleButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Do you want to resize them to original size after transformation? Because it must be scaled to fit original size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this may be it helps you ,

```
CABasicAnimation *fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
    fullRotation.duration = 1;
    fullRotation.repeatCount = 1;
    [button.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
```

Add below framework in your project.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "QuartzCore/CALayer.h"
```

Comment: @Michal:have you got the answer?

Comment: Pefect solution when +UIView:animateWithDuration: with auto layout not works expected!

Answer (score 0):

They don't change their size. They change the frame's size.

Add:

```
CGFrame oldFrame = self.stealthButton.frame;
//Do that for all the buttons
//Do your rotation
self.stealthButton.frame = oldFrame;
```

BUT: By doing so you will actually shrink the button's size. From the user's point of view it will appear much smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the content view set to center.

```
self.stealthButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
self.recButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
self.toggleButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```